# Entity Framework generating index error when instantiating new entity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework

To contextualize my problem I am using C # VS 2017 + EF 6 (DB First) + SQL Server.

Please let me explain the problem: I am instantiating a class to add a record to it. However, in this particular class, when I instantiate, I immediately get an index error out of range. It is an error of type `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

Details:

1. I didn't add values, just instantiated the entity.
2. For testing purposes I removed all relationships from the table involved and the problem continues.
3. I already deleted the table and recreated it in both SQL and EDMX.

Has anyone ever experienced this? Any suggestions?

My code:

```
     using (coletasEntities ctx = new coletasEntities())
     {
           // error happens on line below
           coleta_nota_problema erro = new coleta_nota_problema();

           erro.descricao = msg.Substring(0, 250);
           erro.id_coleta_nota = id;

           ctx.coleta_nota_problema.Add(erro);
           ctx.SaveChanges();
     }

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace Coletas
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class coleta_nota_problema
    {
        public int id_coleta_nota_problema { get; set; }
        public int id_coleta_nota { get; set; }
        public string descricao { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think your problem is more likely with the call to `Substring()`. My guess is `msg` isn't that long.

Comment: @Crowcoder, it sure isn't Substring. The error occurs on the line immediately after the entity instance, not even processing the sequence line. If I remove the line from Substring the problem continues.

Comment: OK, then can we see the constructor of `coelta_nota_problema`?

Comment: What's the stack trace of the exception? Most likely there is a partial extension to this class having a constructor with the offending code.

Comment: what is the KEY property in your calss ? also could you show us the data that you are using (id and msg). Also, you can enable logging on DBContext level using DbContext.Database.Log property which logs all INSERT statements going to database. Alternatives, you can run sql profiler and see INSERT statement that is being sent to database

Comment: @GertArnold, stack is:   StackTrace "   em System.String.Substring(Int32 startIndex, Int32 length)\r\n   em ColetasService.ColetasService.<ProcessaNFsAsync>d__15.MoveNext() na <path>\ColetasService.cs:linha 275" string. But I'm not passing no one value to this class.

Comment: @sam, does it generate insert command even without me asking to add? The error is in class creation.

Comment: yes, DBContext generates INSERT statements and adds to log target. Your class definition is using System.Collections.Generic, but in the given definition I do not see any collection. could you show us complete class definition and also the stack trace if possible. Thank you.

Comment: Then the exception is not on the line you point at, but the next line.

Comment: @Crowcoder, I owe you an apology, you were right: the problem was with substring. I asked to get a substring of 250 but eventually the string had fewer caracters.

Comment: To all, thank you very much: the substring tips, searching the stack, looking at the contents of the "msg" - all combined tips - helped to find the problem.
Thank you all.

Now to everyone who helped: why did the error message come from debugging at the instance line and not the substring line? It is interesting that on another occasion because for testing I put between the creation and substring other lines and he gave no error in the substring line, always in the instance line. This mistake pointing you out of my mind. Any idea why this madness?

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is that sometimes the code file gets out of sync with the debugger symbols which causes bizarre debugging behavior. If that is what is happening try to clean the solution and rebuild and restart visual studio.

Comment: @Crowcoder, I cleaned and also did not solve. Perhaps because I'm debugging a service (yes, it's a service that is attached to debugging) is causing this problem with the line indication. It served as an (painful) experience to be aware of the error messages.

Comment: Yes, if the symbols don't exactly match the source code you can have this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To isolate the problem, try assigning a hard coded value first and see if it the error goes away:

```
erro.descricao = "hello"; // any arbitrary text
erro.id_coleta_nota = 1000; // any arbitrary integer unique if this is the key
erro.id_coleta_nota_problema = 1000; // any arbitrary integer
```

As mentioned in the comments in your post, the following line is most probably the culprit:

```
erro.descricao = msg.Substring(0, 250);
```

Comment: I'm changed the line to fix the error:

if (msg.lenth > 250) msg = msg.substring(0,250)